# Ошибка сборки Resurrection Remix 6.2.1 (Android Oreo)

Tags: android, сборка, обработка-ошибок

```
1 error generated.
[ 77% 59601/76896] //frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0:android.frameworks.displayser....frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++/gen/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/EventCallbackAll.cpp
FAILED: /media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0/android_arm_armv7-a-neon_krait_static_core/obj/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/EventCallbackAll.o 
PWD=/proc/self/cwd /usr/bin/ccache prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4053586/bin/clang++ -c -Iframeworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-short-enums -no-canonical-prefixes -DNDEBUG -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -fdebug-prefix-map=/proc/self/cwd= -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-expansion-to-defined -fdebug-prefix-map=$PWD/= -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=date-time -nostdlibinc -msoft-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mcpu=krait -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -D__ARM_FEATURE_LPAE=1 -Iexternal/libcxx/include -Iexternal/libcxxabi/include -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/core/base/include -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.0/android.hidl.manager@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.1/android.hidl.manager@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/base/1.0/android.hidl.base@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Isystem/libhwbinder/include -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++/gen -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Isystem/core/include -Isystem/media/audio/include -Ihardware/libhardware/include -Ihardware/libhardware_legacy/include -Ihardware/ril/include -Ilibnativehelper/include -Iframeworks/native/include -Iframeworks/native/opengl/include -Iframeworks/av/include -isystem bionic/libc/arch-arm/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/scsi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/uapi -Ilibnativehelper/include_deprecated -Wall -Werror -D__ANDROID_DEBUGGABLE__ -target arm-linux-androideabi -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/arm-linux-androideabi/bin -DANDROID_STRICT -fPIC -D_USING_LIBCXX -std=gnu++14 -Wsign-promo -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-null-dereference -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_THREAD_SAFETY_ANNOTATIONS -Wno-thread-safety-negative -fno-rtti -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=return-type -MD -MF '/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0/android_arm_armv7-a-neon_krait_static_core/obj/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/EventCallbackAll.o'.d -o '/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0/android_arm_armv7-a-neon_krait_static_core/obj/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/EventCallbackAll.o' '/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++/gen/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/EventCallbackAll.cpp'
out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++/gen/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/EventCallbackAll.cpp:320:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'setRequestingSid'
            setRequestingSid(::android::hardware::details::gServiceSidMap.get(_hidl_impl, false));
            ^
1 error generated.
[ 77% 59603/76896] //frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0:android.frameworks.displayser...frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++/gen/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/DisplayServiceAll.cpp
FAILED: /media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0/android_arm_armv7-a-neon_krait_static_core/obj/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/DisplayServiceAll.o 
PWD=/proc/self/cwd /usr/bin/ccache prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4053586/bin/clang++ -c -Iframeworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0 -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-short-enums -no-canonical-prefixes -DNDEBUG -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -fdebug-prefix-map=/proc/self/cwd= -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-expansion-to-defined -fdebug-prefix-map=$PWD/= -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=date-time -nostdlibinc -msoft-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mcpu=krait -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -D__ARM_FEATURE_LPAE=1 -Iexternal/libcxx/include -Iexternal/libcxxabi/include -Isystem/libhidl/base/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libutils/include -Isystem/core/libbacktrace/include -Isystem/core/liblog/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Isystem/libhidl/transport/include -Isystem/core/base/include -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.0/android.hidl.manager@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/manager/1.1/android.hidl.manager@1.1_genc++_headers/gen -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/system/libhidl/transport/base/1.0/android.hidl.base@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Isystem/libhwbinder/include -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++/gen -I/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++_headers/gen -Isystem/core/include -Isystem/media/audio/include -Ihardware/libhardware/include -Ihardware/libhardware_legacy/include -Ihardware/ril/include -Ilibnativehelper/include -Iframeworks/native/include -Iframeworks/native/opengl/include -Iframeworks/av/include -isystem bionic/libc/arch-arm/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/scsi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/uapi -Ilibnativehelper/include_deprecated -Wall -Werror -D__ANDROID_DEBUGGABLE__ -target arm-linux-androideabi -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/arm-linux-androideabi/bin -DANDROID_STRICT -fPIC -D_USING_LIBCXX -std=gnu++14 -Wsign-promo -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-null-dereference -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_THREAD_SAFETY_ANNOTATIONS -Wno-thread-safety-negative -fno-rtti -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=return-type -MD -MF '/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0/android_arm_armv7-a-neon_krait_static_core/obj/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/DisplayServiceAll.o'.d -o '/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0/android_arm_armv7-a-neon_krait_static_core/obj/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/DisplayServiceAll.o' '/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo/out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++/gen/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/DisplayServiceAll.cpp'
out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/android.frameworks.displayservice@1.0_genc++/gen/android/frameworks/displayservice/1.0/DisplayServiceAll.cpp:267:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'setRequestingSid'
            setRequestingSid(::android::hardware::details::gServiceSidMap.get(_hidl_impl, false));
            ^
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
13:52:35 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (03:54:15 (hh:mm:ss)) ####

mycat@mycat:/media/mycat/DATA/ANDROID/rr-oreo$
```